# Keep two activities of the same class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I searched over the web and on Stackoverflow, but I didn't found the problem (and it is odd, cause I think is a common problem, isn't it?)

I got two activity classes, A and B. From A I can go to B, and the stack will be AB (And I can go back to A when I want).

The problem is that I want to open a second instance of B, call it B*. I want the stack to be AB(B*), so I can go back to B. I looked at the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), in the hope to find a FLAG that make this possible. I read the description and nothing made me think it can help ...

Tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`, these both in conjuction,     `this.moveTaskToBack(true);` (actually I didn't know what was its meaning, but it sounded quite good

Comment: Why don't use fragments?

Comment: Actually I simplified the problem: "B" already contains 4 fragments (they are tabs), and A contains 3. In wich way could fragments help me in this?

Comment: If you want two different instances of the save activity, then most probably you have awful app design

Comment: @AlexanderZhak: "B" is the "Create Customer Activity". In My app every Customer has an Associate Customer, and I have to create this Associate Customer during the creation of the first. So, I am creating customer Alpha (Activity B). During the creation, I touch a button that allow me to create its associate Beta. Is there another better way than using a "B*" activity?

Comment: So create a fragment "CustomerCreationFragment" and just use it everytime you need to create an user

Comment: @PedroOliveira: In this way, there will be an Activity, containing a Fragment, containg four fragments, did I catcht it right? I knew that a Fragment cannot contain a Fragment ... But even if, it is kinda tricky, isn't it?

Comment: You can use getChildFragmentManager() for API level 17+. You can also use support library for API level 11 to 16

Comment: remains the problem that the final result will be very tricky ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a comment, I suppose, but it appears to be rather long. Nevertheless, let's go to the subject. If I understand you correctly, the requirement is something as follows:

1. As an application user I should be able to create a new customer.
2. Each customer should have associated customer.

You have one entity: *Customer*. The entity can have associations.
If two different customers use the same associated customer (and I don't see any reason why it is not possible in real world), then we have the set possible flows:

1. New customer needs new associated customer
2. New customer needs existing associated customer
3. Existing customer needs new associated customer
4. Existing customer needs existing assotiated customer.

Potentially, a customer can have an associated customer, which has an associated customer...

*Another flow:*
You add a new customer, then you add a new associated customer and save it, but then you decide that you don't want to add a new customer. What will happen in this case?

I'd follow some state-based approach. Something like:
a) User adds a new customer and saves it. Customer is now in "Awaiting association" state and cannot be used.
b) User adds a new customer in the same way they added the first one. It also enters "Awaiting association" state on save.

Now two customers can be associated with one another, which will produce "Associater - Associatee" pair (frankly speaking, I doubt such words exist in English, but you get the idea)

Comment: Yes, that is kinda the logic.
Flows 2. and 4. are managed in a different way, with a list in which I can select the existing customers and hit"ok" to associate them, so, there's no problem in that.

So, about your solution: informatically is cool, but that is absolutely user unfriendly (even without considering that my customer's will is this). With your solution the user should 
1. Hit New Customer
2. Save
3. Hit *again* New Customer
4. Open a list and *search* the first -and that is awful-
5. Associate
6. Save. But that is what I want: 1. Hit New Customer 2. Hit New Associate
4. Save
5. Save